# Logical & bitwise AND

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, logical-operators

I am using bitwise operators to store some boolean values in a variable. I assume i'm storing them appropiately, although here are my assignments:

```
int bit = 0;
bit |= 1;
bit |= 2;
bit |= 4;
bit |= 8;
```

What i am unsure of is the checking part. I have a simple knowledge about the difference between **logical** and **bitwise** operators. Here's how i check the values:

```
if ((bit & 1) && (bit & 2) && (bit & 8)) {
    std::cout << "a" << std::endl;
} 
else {
    std::cout << "b" << std::endl;  
}
```

I want to know if that kind of conditional is correct (i've done some tests, but i might be missing something) and also i want to know if i can check multiple bits at the same time, for example:

```
if (bit && (1 & 2 & 8) {
    std::cout << "a" << std::endl;
} 
else {
    std::cout << "b" << std::endl;  
}
```

I know that the last won't work as desired (at least that's what tests gave me), but i wanted to illustrate my idea.

Comment: You, yourself get to decide if its correct. Should it be true if bits 1, 2, and 8 are set? If so, then it's correct. The `if (bit && (1 & 2 & 8))` proposal will never evaluate to true, under no circumstances, so it's obviously wrong.

Comment: Your last example should be `if (bit & (1|2|8))`. I think that would work. It would create a mask by OR'ing 1, 2, 8 together, then AND that with `bit`, if bit 1, 2 or 8 were set, it would be true.

Comment: Yes, i know that it is up to my own criteria. However, i wanted to know if it would work as required (and that's what my tests said) or if i should take other alternative.

Comment: Perhaps see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit

Comment: `if (bit & (1|2|8))` will evaluate as true if ANY of the 3 bits is set.  If you want to check if ALL of the 3 bits are set, you have to use `if ((bit & (1|2|8)) == (1|2|8))` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i want to know if i can check multiple bits at the same time

Yes, you can do that but your code is not correct.

1. `1 & 2 & 8` will always be zero. You need to use `1 | 2 | 8`.
2. `bit && (1 & 2 & 8)` is not correct because of the above.

You can use:

```
if ( (bit & (1 | 2 | 8)) == (1 | 2 | 8) ) {
    std::cout << "a" << std::endl;
} 
else {
    std::cout << "b" << std::endl;  
}
```

The expression `(bit & 1) && (bit & 2) && (bit & 8)` is logically the same as the expression `(bit & (1 | 2 | 8)) == (1 | 2 | 8)`

See it working at https://ideone.com/KdGjiO.

Comment: I've tried your example code and it doesn't work as expected. Today i used a similar code (instead of bit & (1... i wrote bit && (1...) but it didn't work either. If i change the 8 with a 16, it will print a anyways, wheter i **OR**ed it on my assignments or not. Shouldn't it print b if i use sixteen?

Comment: @Rezniaq, I can't tell what could be wrong without a [mcve].

Comment: I am using no more than what's written on my question. I replaced my if statement with yours, and changed your 8 to 16. If i copy my main it will be the same as rewriting my question, but i can do it if you want to.

Comment: "*The expression `(bit & 1) && (bit & 2) && (bit & 8)` is logically the same as the expression `bit & (1 | 2 | 8)`*" - no, it is not. `bit & (1 | 2 | 8)` is logically the same as `(bit & 1) || (bit & 2) || (bit & 8)`.  The correct expression would be `(bit & (1 | 2 | 8)) == (1 | 2 | 8)` instead.

Comment: Yes, your code IS working, however, it doesn't accomplish my desired output. As i said, if i change your 8 with a 16, it will not work, but the original code will. Check it at ideone.com/npwtHQ

Comment: @Rezniaq, the error was pointed out by Remy Lebeau. Try the updated logic.

Comment: @Rezniaq: `bit & (1 | 2 | 16)` is the same as `(bit & 1) || (bit & 2) || (bit & 16)`, which is not the same as `(bit & 1) && (bit & 2) && (bit & 16)`.  There is a big difference between checking if ANY bits are set vs checking if ALL bits are set

Comment: @Remy Lebeau @R Sahu Thank you both!

Answer (score 2):

> The bitwise AND operator compares each bit of the first operand to the
>   corresponding bit of the second operand. If both bits are 1, the
>   corresponding result bit is set to 1. Otherwise, the corresponding
>   result bit is set to 0.

Since the AND operation if you want to check n. bit of the value you must AND it with 2^(n-1). If the bit is set the result of the bitwise operation will be greater than zero that means value is logically true otherwise it will be zero (or logically false)

```
if ((bit & 1) && (bit & 2) && (bit & 8))
```

this expression is suits what you want to do

```
if (bit && (1 & 2 & 8))
```

but 1 & 2 & 8 will produce always zero. The correct expression is:

```
if ((bit & (1 | 2 | 8)) == (1 | 2 | 8))
```

Comment: You need to use `&` instead of `&&`. But note that `if (bit & (1|2|8))` will evaluate to true if ANY of the 3 bits is set. If you want to check if ALL of the 3 bits are set, you have to use `if ((bit & (1|2|8)) == (1|2|8))` instead.

Comment: I haven't noticed the `&&` operator since I did copy/paste.Thanks for the correction, I have read the question again and the correct expression should be `if ((bit & (1|2|8)) == (1|2|8))` as you said.

Comment: Thank you very much! I would mark your answer as correct but i can't mark two. R Sahu's one also provides a direct answer to my first question (if i can check multiple bit at a time). I hope you don't get offended.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a binary literal to compare:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int bit = 0;
    bit |= 1;
    bit |= 2;
    bit |= 4;
    bit |= 8;

    if ((bit & 0b1111) == 0b1111) {
        std::cout << "YES!";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Or as a function:

```
bool compareIntBool(const int bit, const int compareTo) {
    return (bit & compareTo) == compareTo ? true : false;
}
```

Then call it with a binary literal:

```
if (compareIntBool(bit, 0b1111)) {
    std::cout << "YES";
}
```

Comment: Although your answer doesn't directly address my question, it's something i didn't know before, so i'll thank you. I've never thought of nor seen binary literals.

Answer (score 0):

Difference between both are simple
&&-First statement is false means it cannot check  second value
&-It is check both the value either the first value is true or false

Comment: This is not the solution of the problem. please put this in comment section.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an alternative implementation of your first example:

```
static const char * const table[] = {
    "a", "a", "a", "a",
    "a", "a", "a", "a", 
    "a", "a", "a", "b",
    "a", "a", "a", "b", 
};

std::cout << table[bit] << std::endl;
```

---

Of course, it might be safer to do the lookup as `table[bit&0xF]` instead.

Comment: The purpose of the question is to ask about how to use bitwise operators in general, not about how to output a value based on bits.  This answer doesn't address the real question.